# Map a method to a field with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

**I want to use Automapper and need to map a method to the field(such as command part).
How can I do it?**
This my first Code

```cs
     foreach(source item in sources)
      {

     ss.ServerStatusType = ServerStatusTypeName(item);
     ss.A = item.A ;
     ss.B =item.B;
     destinations.Add(dto);
}
```

**I want Use Automapper and I just have problem with  ServerStatusTypeName method**

```cs
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>   
     cfg.CreateMap<IList<source >, IList<Destination>>());

IList<Source> statuses = context.Sp_ServerUpdateStatus(userName).ToList();

            var mapper = new Mapper(config);
            IList<Source> dto = mapper.Map<IList<Destination>>(statuses);
```

**Everything is ok just ss.ServerStatusType is null because I use a method to fill this item**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
class YourObjectProfile : Profile
    {
        public YourObjectProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<UI_Object, Domain_Object>()
                .ForMember(c => c.name, p => p.MapFrom(dbc => dbc.name));

            CreateMap<Domain_Object, UI_Object>()
                .ForMember(dbc => dbc.name, dbp => dbp.MapFrom(c => c.name));
        }   
    }
```

Comment: No I can't ,I need use my method.     destination dto = mapper.Map < destination > (item);//this my method
    // ss.ServerStatusType = ServerStatusTypeName(item);

Answer (score 0):

**I use this code and it is ok**

```
 CreateMap<Sp_ServerUpdateStatus_Result, ServerStatus>()
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.ServerStatusType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src=> ServerStatusTypeName(src))
                );
```

...
ServerStatusTypeName(src) is a method